# Selenium - Get text inside of table cells

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

Trying to get the text inside of the table cells, but have no luck.

I am trying to get the text inside of these cells:

[image]

**(th and td)**

The code works, kind of. It prints out the value as a normal " " (space).

code:

```
driver.get('https://www.komplett.se/product/1165487/datorutrustning/datorkomponenter/chassibarebone/big-tower/phanteks-eclipse-p500-air')

parent_table = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/main/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/section[2]/div/div/div")
count_of_tables = len(parent_table.find_elements_by_xpath("./table"))

for x in range(count_of_tables):
    parent_tr = driver.find_element_by_xpath(f"/html/body/div[2]/main/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/section[2]/div/div/div/table[{x + 1}]/tbody")
    count_of_tr = len(parent_tr.find_elements_by_xpath("./tr"))
    print(count_of_tr)
    for y in range(count_of_tr):
        th = driver.find_element_by_xpath(f'/html/body/div[2]/main/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/section[2]/div/div/div/table[{x + 1}]/tbody/tr[{y+1}]/th')
        td = driver.find_element_by_xpath(f'/html/body/div[2]/main/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/section[2]/div/div/div/table[{x + 1}]/tbody/tr[{y + 1}]/td')
        print(th.text)
        print(td.text)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for y in range(count_of_tr):
    th = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
        f'/html/body/div[2]/main/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/section[2]/div/div/div/table[{x + 1}]/tbody/tr[{y+1}]/th')
    td = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
        f'/html/body/div[2]/main/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/section[2]/div/div/div/table[{x + 1}]/tbody/tr[{y + 1}]/td')
    print(th.get_attribute("textContent"))
    print(td.get_attribute("textContent"))
```

use get attribute text content as , text will retrieve text visible in view port only